# Relating knowledge articles to cases

Tags: knowledge

We enabled knowledge in our salesforce organization. We have configured the page layout to have cases and have the new button enabled in the related list.

Below is confirmation that this exists:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand what security settings are not allowing me to link knowledge articles to cases.